# Find MongoDB records where status is a, b or c and it has some array which is greater than 0

Tags: java, mongodb

I am struggling to build up a query for one of the criteria, I have a documents like this:

```
[
 {
    "status": "a"
 },
 {
    "status": "b"
 },
 {
    "status": "foo"
 },
 {
    "status": "a",
    "flightDetails": [
        {
            "test": "xyz"
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

My criteria to select like this:

- Get all data where status is either `a`, `b` or `c`, or
- Get all data where status is either `a`, `b` or `c`  and `flightDetails`, which size is > 0
- Where not all documents contains `flightDetails` key.

I tried my java code like this:

```
BasicDBObject inQuery = new BasicDBObject();
inQuery.append("status", new BasicDBObject("$nin", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));

BasicDBObject inQuery2 = new BasicDBObject();
inQuery2.append("$where", "return Object.keys( this.flightDetails").length > 0");

BasicDBList criteria = new BasicDBList();
criteria.add(inQuery);
criteria.add(inQuery2);

BasicDBObject finalQuery = new BasicDBObject("$or",criteria);
```

But it returns all the data, seems my query is not correct. I searched lot and based on some SO answers, I tried to build query. Can someone kindly help me in this? Since I am beginner in NoSQL and MongoDB and started on this few days back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dot notation for the "0" element of the array along with [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)  means that it has some content, and of course exists:

```
BasicDBObject query = BasicDBObject("status", 
    new BasicDBObject("$in", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
)
    .append("flightDetails.0",
      new BasicDBObject("$exists",true)
    );
```

Which is:

```
{
    "status": { "$in": [ "a","b","c" ] },
    "flightDetails.0": { "$exists": true }
}
```

For those used to the JSON notation.

To incorporate "no array at all" just contruct the **`$or`** condition:

```
{
    "status": { "$in": [ "a","b","c" ] },
    "$or": [
        { "flightDetails.0": { "$exists": true } },
        { "flightDetails": { "$exists": false } }
    ]
}
```

Or for Java:

```
BasicDBObject query = BasicDBObject("status", 
    new BasicDBObject("$in", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
)
    .append("$or",Arrays.<Object>asList(
        new BasicDBObject("flightDetails.0",
            new BasicDBObject("$exists",true)
        ),
        new BasicDBObject("flightDetails",
            new BasicDBObject("$exists",false)
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I will check on it.